# VI replace a custom number of characters from a custom position

Tags: text-editor, vi, substitution, character-replacement

There is a text file like that

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/false

daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/bin/false
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/bin/false
ftp:x:14:11:ftp:/srv/ftp:/bin/false
http:x:33:33:http:/srv/http:/bin/false
```

How to replace in VI all characters in strings 2-4 from 2nd to 5th to 'X'?

UPD:
it's smth like: :2,4s//X/g
I guess I need a regular expression

UPD2: `:2,4s/^\(.\)...\|^$/\1XXX/ | 2,4s/^$/ XXX/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vim only

Try this command:

```
:2,4s/\%2c.../XXX/
```

Where:

- `2,4` is for `in strings 2-4`
- `\%2c...` is for `from 2nd to 5th`
- `XXX` is for `to 'X'`

### Both Vim and Vi

As Vi doesn't have \%c, this command should be used instead:

```
:2,4s/^\(.\).../\1XXX/
```

### Resources

- [`:help :range`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3arange)
- [`:help /ordinary-atom`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/ordinary-atom)

Comment: Substitute pattern match failed.
Thanx for reference

Comment: Are you using vim or vi? vi doesn't have `\%c`. How about this command: `:2,4s/^\(.\).../\1XXX/`?

Comment: How can I change regular expression so it will not ignore empty strings?

Comment: You can add `\|^$`, but it won't insert any character at first column. I think applying two substitutions in a row would be a better choice (the second one could look like `:2,4s/^$/ XXX/`).

Comment: The thing is to do this in one command. Explain please how to add this `\|^$`

Comment: Just add it to regular expression, like this: `:2,4s/^\(.\)...\|^$/\1XXX/`.

Comment: vi probably doesn't like that there is no capture in the second regular expression, maybe `:2,4s/^\(.\)...\|^\(\)$/\1XXX/` will work.

Comment: I've tried it different ways and concluded that vi doesn't understand "OR" expression in this case. So you was right, two substitutions in a row will be good solution. I used the following expression `:2,4s/^\(.\)...\|^$/\1XXX/ | 2,4s/^$/ XXX/`